# invalid pointer when using strings for generic class

Tags: c++, string, c++11, pointers

So this is for my data structures class and I am struggling to understand why I am getting the error:  invalid pointer: 0x00000000023ce048 ***. It only happens when I define my generic class using strings: `NSequence<string> v3(10);`

It should be noted that using int or even a different class worked fine. However, as soon as I write the line: `NSequence<string> v3(10);` I get the pointer error and I have no idea why?

UPDATE:
I've found that it was actually my destructor class that was causing the error. However, I now have no idea why this would cause an error specifically with string?

```
template<typename T>
NSequence<T>::~NSequence()
{
     delete items;
}
```

Here is the definition of my class:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

/* XXX: Implement all member functions for NSequence in NSequence.hpp */

template <typename T>
class NSequence
{
  public:
    explicit NSequence( int initSize = 0 ); 
      
  private:
    int numOfItems;
    int totalCapacity;
    T * items;
};

#include "NSequence.hpp"  // do not change this line 

#endif
```

Here is my constructor function:

```
template<typename T>
NSequence<T>::NSequence(int initSize)
{
        if(initSize==0)
                initSize=1;

        numOfItems = initSize;
        totalCapacity = initSize;
        items = new T[totalCapacity];

}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem. See if you can reduce the program to a [mre] with a similar error result.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you apparently are OK with an initialization like `NSequence<string> huh(-9);`. (If you are not OK with negative sizes, change the parameter type from `int` to `unsigned`.)

Comment: Remember that delete and delete[] are different things http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/